# Response anomaly after process repeats three times

Tags: python

This is my full code:

```
from random import randint
currency = float(5.0)
while currency > 0:
    start = input("Do you wish to gamble? Y/N ")
    if start == "Y":
        numbers = []
        currency = currency - 0.2
        di = randint (1,6)
        numbers.append(di)
        dice = randint (1,6)
        numbers.append(dice) 
        thrice = randint (1,6)
        numbers.append(thrice)
        print(numbers[0])
        print(numbers[1])
        print(numbers[2])
        if numbers[0] == numbers[1] or numbers[0] == numbers[2] or numbers[1] == numbers[2]:
            currency = currency + 1.0
            print("You win £1!","Your current balance is: £",currency)
        elif numbers[0] == numbers[1] and numbers[0] == numbers[2]:
            currency = currency + 2.0
            print("Jackpot! You win £2!","Your current balance is: £",currency)
        else:
            print("Too bad!","You're currency is: £",currency)
    elif start == "N":
        print("Your final total was: £",currency)
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid Response")
```

And the response I get after accepting as "Y" three times is:

```
Do you wish to gamble? Y/N Y
1
6
2
Too bad! You're currency is: £ 4.8
Do you wish to gamble? Y/N Y
2
4
2
You win £1! Your current balance is: £ 5.6
Do you wish to gamble? Y/N Y
1
1
6
You win £1! Your current balance is: £ 6.3999999999999995
```

I do not understand why this is happening, the code checks out, and this issue repeats consistently on the third run no matter the outcome of the RNG and will always end in number.999999999999995.

Comment: Please Ignore Missing Indentation....python is indentation dependent, please fix your indentation

Comment: Asking python programmers to: **Please Ignore Missing Indentation** is asking us to ignore the question. (btw, there is simpler code you could have posted to show this effect)

Comment: Sorry it was a formatting issue with the website, I couldn't bother to fix it.

Comment: @PatrickCake then we won't bother answering.

Comment: PS: you dont the the `float` in `currency = float(5.0)`.

Comment: @TwistedSim thanks for your input but that doesn't pertain to the problem, same issue occurs.

Comment: It was not trying to fix your isssu. I was giving you a tip.

Answer (score 1):

floating number could not be presented.

try to using format

```
"{0:.1f}".format(currency)
```

Comment: No dice, sadly.

Comment: @PatrickCake I think you will encounter floating number issue for all the programming language